# MQ right way to close connection

Tags: java, ibm-mq, connection-leaks

I saw lots of examples like
http://hursleyonwmq.wordpress.com/2007/05/29/simplest-sample-applications-using-websphere-mq-jms/, even on IBM publib. As I guess this code had a flaw: Queue connection closed in main block, and not in **finally** as I expected.

What is the right way to close MQ connection without leaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to do it in finally.
i.e.

```
finally
{
   try
   {
      session.close();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      System.err.println("session.close() : " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
   }

   try
   {
      connection.close();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      System.err.println("connection.close() : " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IBM MQ since 8.0.0 (since 2014) release supports JMS 2.0. So all QueueConnection, QueueSession QueueSender and QueueReceiver implements java.lang.AutoCloseable [see ibm mq spec](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/mq/jms/MQQueueConnection.html)

```
try (QueueConnection connection = connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
     //create a session that is not transacted and has an acknowledgment mode 
     QueueSession session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)) 
    {
        Queue queue = session.createQueue("queue:///Q1");

        try (QueueSender sender = session.createSender(queue);
             QueueReceiver receiver = session.createReceiver(queue);) 
        {
            //getting and sending messages...
        }

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        //handling jms exceptions...
    }
```

or using JMS 2.0 JMSContext

```
try (JMSContext context = connectionFactory.createContext();) 
    {
        context.createProducer().send(context.createQueue("queue:///Q1"), "text");
    } catch (JMSRuntimeException ex) {
        // handle exception (details omitted)
    }
```